# How to run a specific unit test in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have unit tests in a package named `school-info` and there is a test function called `repeat_students_should_not_get_full_marks`.

I can run all tests in the module by `cargo test --package school_info`.

`cargo test test-name` will match and run tests which contain `test_name` though this wasn't helpful.

How can I run only the test `repeat_students_should_not_get_full_marks` without running all the tests? I could not find a command in the documentation to do it.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Using `cargo test test-name` filters tests that contain **test-name**. It is possible that it can run multiple tests. It doesn't matter if the test function is in some `mod` or not, it still able to execute multiple test.

You can avoid this by adding  `-- --exact` as argument.

If your test is not in any mod you can simply execute like this:

```
cargo test test_fn_name -- --exact
```

Otherwise you need to provide test with full namespace:

```
cargo test test_mod_name::test_fn_name -- --exact
```

For your case the solution will be :

```
cargo test --package school_info repeat_students_should_not_get_full_marks -- --exact
```

---

**See also:**

- [How to suppress empty outputs of cargo test when running a specific test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283680/how-to-suppress-empty-outputs-of-cargo-test-when-running-a-specific-test) *(multiple projects in same workspace)*

Comment: Not sure if this was something that changed in the last few years, but `cargo test test-name` does not filter for tests that _start with_ `test-name`, but instead filter for tests which _contain_ `test-name`.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I am not sure also, I might have misjudge back then but thanks for pointing out, edited.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore- `unrecognized option --exact`

Comment: @Jim are you using `cargo` to execute tests? or `rustc` ? If you are using `rustc` you need to compile your source first:  `rustc --test src/test_file.rs` then execute the test with running the compiled binary, example: `.\test_file.exe --exact test_name`

Comment: This kinda works, but when I run `cargo test <some filter> -- --exact` I still get ~3 screen pages of basically always saying "Running unittests ... running 0 test" for all other modules with tests, and for one time ""Running unittests ... running 1 test" for the module that did match. I took me a few minutes to even spot the "running 1 test" amongst all the noise. Is there a way to make cargo omit the output for the modules that didn't match?

Comment: @bluenote10 I haven't observed this kind of a behavior, maybe my test project is a bit simpler than yours, could you please provide more information like how your project structured and which versions of cargo/rustc you are using. You can even post a new question if it makes more comfortable and benefits to others for an unknown case, if you do please share the link here, thanks.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thanks for the encouragement! It turns out that the issue is related to mixing libraries with binaries, and it gets worsened in "workspace" projects that have many of them. I've created a [follow-up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283680/1804173) containing a minimal reproduction example.