# How to disable a unit test in rust with an attribute?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

A module contains multiple tests like following:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests_cases {

    /*
    #[test]
    fn test_1() {
        let a = 1;
        let b = 2;
        println!("{},{}", a, b);
        assert_ne!(a, b);
    }
    */

    #[test]
    fn test_2() {
        let c = 1;
        let d = 1;
        println!("currently working on this: {},{}", c, d);
        assert_eq!(c, d);
    }
}
```

When working on the second tests with output visible
(`cargo test -- --nocapture`),
I do not want to see the output of the first tests.

Is there an option to disable the commented unit test? Or is there an option to just run the second unit test?

Comment: If you only want the output of a single test, you can request this like `cargo test module::tests::test_2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a specific unit test in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585804/how-to-run-a-specific-unit-test-in-rust)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Another option is to add the `#[ignore]` attribute.

```rust
#[ignore]
#[test]
fn test_1() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    println!("{},{}", a, b);
    assert_ne!(a, b);
}
```

This adds a nice colored ignored to the test results.

```
test tests::test_1 ... ignored
test tests::test_2 ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 1 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.03s
```

---

Source:
[Ignoring Some Tests Unless Specifically Requested](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html#ignoring-some-tests-unless-specifically-requested)

Comment: A reason for ignoring can be stated with `#[ignore = "ignore for now"]`

Answer (score 6):

If you remove the `#[test]` attribute from the unwanted test, then `cargo test` will ignore it.