# run specific .rs file

Tags: rust, clion, rust-cargo

quick introduction, I came from python I have studied it by myself, and now I'm trying to learn Rust. I find it a bit confusing.

I have a `main.rs` file and other `.rs` files in the `src` directory just to have cleaner and organized code, as each of these other files do specific tasks and the `main.rs` just put all together with a simple CLI.

I just wanna test a single of these `.rs` file, or even a single `fn` inside to check if the result is what I am expecting.

How can I do that? It's simple, it's stupid, but I have read around and found nothing that could help me in the end.

I read [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html), where it talks about making a `tests` folder and then using `cargo test`, I've done it, but it still runs the `src/main.rs` instead of what I have put in `tests`. BTW I'm using CLion with the Rust plugin.

Sorry if this is somewhat a duplicate, I looked around but I didn't found an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a specific unit test in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585804/how-to-run-a-specific-unit-test-in-rust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2023-09-01:** A related feature is now available as experimental in rust (cargo) nightly. See:

- https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3424-cargo-script.html
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html#script

This functionality is not really part of cargo, but there are some crates that do it. The one I'm most familiar with is [rust-script](https://crates.io/crates/rust-script). It works with a hashbang like `#!/usr/bin/env rust-script` at the top of your script, then run it with `./script.rs`. You can even specify dependencies in the script which get parsed out of some special comments.

Otherwise uou can compile single files directly with `rustc`, but managing dependencies, etc. can be complicated.

Edit: Sorry yes - it looks like you're trying to write/run tests. The page you linked in the book should cover what you're trying to do. I'm not sure what you mean by "it still runs the `src/main.rs` instead of what I have put in `tests`". Do you have `mod tests` in `main.rs` as well?

Comment: First, thanks for your answer!
I kinda figured out the issue, I had an error on `src/main.rs` and even if in theory `cargo test` runs only what it's inside the `tests` directory, I think it still builds everything, so my program was crashing for an error in `src/main.rs`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put specific `.rs` files in the `./src/bin/` to do this.

For example, you can have `./src/bin/test_1.rs` and run it with:

```
cargo run --bin test_1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compile any .rs file using `rustc your_file.rs` command as long as the file contains `main()` function. `rustc` will fail if there isn't main function:

```
error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `abc`
 --> abc.rs:5:2
  |
5 | }
  |  ^ consider adding a `main` function to `abc.rs`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0601`.
```

but you can skip this by marking the file as library crate instead of bin:

`rustc you_file.rs --crate-type=lib`